# using Jquery in my .js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I am very new to web development and Javascript in general and I hae done some Jquery coding by adding my code in my HTMl code all the time. Now, I just moved the same code to my .Js file  and my console shows me following error:

> $ is not defined [Break On This Error] $(document).ready(function () {

It just says JQuery is not defined. It means that I can not refer to Jquery or any other Javascript files in my Js file?

Or there is something that I am missing here?

Comment: Are you including jQuery first?

Comment: Wait, I am sorry for not being detailed enough. Basically, I decided not to add JQuery in my HTMl page and wanted to create a model in which whatever functionality my Javascript is using, I want it to be added in my Javascript. Some thing like using statement in C#. Is it possible?

Comment: No, JavaScript has no way to do that, really.  You can append a script element to the DOM with JavaScript to load stuff that way, but that's a weird, non-traditional way of doing it.

Comment: [RequireJS](http://www.requirejs.org/) would let you do something like that.

Comment: Yeah I went through many things and I think RequireJS is the only way. I really wonder why does Javascript does not support something simple like this?

Comment: @Californicated: C# is not as magic as you are trying to portray it. You cannot just add a `using` and have it work; you have to add an assembly reference if it is not already referenced. JavaScript's equivalent, I guess, would be adding a `script` tag and no `using` is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just include jQuery before your script is called

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

For other jQuery stuff available in CDN, see this:
http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#CDN_Hosted_jQuery

Update: This is as close to "using" as you can get, in my mind. It's not required to download the jQuery library to your system or host it on your server.

Comment: It's only necessary if you need to either edit the original jquery, or if your server is on some intranet which has no external access.

Comment: what is only necessary? update: got you. you're referring to downloading the library :)

Comment: sorry I mean it would only be necessary to download the Jquery file if you need to edit it or if you will be using it on a page that will have no external access to the internet

Answer (score 0):

in your html did you move the whole jquery file into your .js file? you shoudl have it as something like:

```
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"type="text/javascript"></script>
// Now load your .js file
<script type="text/javascript" src="your .js file"></script>
```

Also if you downloaded jquery forget about it, the top link means you're loading jquery from google so you'll always have the latest version, I really cant be much more help unless you upload your code, sorry.

Comment: Actually I am trying to load it from JS file not from html..... Something weird.... I know....... But I think it should be doable..

Comment: I think you would need some add in code, javascript was originally intended to be used with html pages and that's basically it, anything that runs in a browser can run javascript, what set up are you using and if you're not using it for a web page what are you trying to plug it into, because if you're trying to call it from another program or anything you will need some language-dependent plugins, sorry by set up i mean what's your end-goal, and what languages etc are you using?

Comment: Answer does not provide any help